# MySQL Frontend that displays foreign rows nested within a table's rows?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, frontend

I once came across a MySQL Frontend app that displayed foreign linked rows within the parent row, if for instance the `Client` table has a foreign key to the `Suburb` table:

[image]
<sub>(source: [vb123.com](http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/00_docs/sdfigure1.gif))</sub>

Do you know of any Frontend that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL Maestro** popups sub datasheets for foreign rows

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/maestro/screenshots/getting_started/data_grid/

**SQL Manager for MySQL** can view table data in "multilevel mode":

http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/manager/screenshots/777

**SQL Edge** has a "Relationship view" that shows foreign rows:

http://www.baybreezesoft.com/images/treevw.jpg

Comment: Nice compilation. Thanks for including the frontend I found (SQL Edge from Baybreeze) in this list. I deleted my answer because of the same. I really liked the nested rows displayed in "SQL Manager", though I find the Relationship view in "SQL Edge" quite fantastic - only that you have to click on a node to view the actual data contents.

Comment: But still, the software I was looking for is NOT listed. Since you've found all these when people have said there were no frontends that supported this feature, I hope you find the one I was looking for somehow. Although your answers are practical, I **cannot award** you the bounty until I find that particular frontend. Or until time runs out :)

Comment: **+350** - Damn. Time ran out before I could find the software I was looking for. Too bad, but thanks for the 3 other contenders and congrats on winning the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

[phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net) has the option

see [server configuration](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#relation) and [relation page](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/relation) in the pma wiki

Comment: setup the phpmyadmin helper table (control user), if you are using myISAM add the relationships. then, when viewing recordsets, click on options and check relational display field

Comment: But it is very limited (can show only one field from foreign table) and will work in opposite way - while browsing events you can see student name in student_id column. The goal here is to view all events attached to student while browsing students table.

Comment: create a view or write a simple join?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not even a frontend worth talking about, being completely web based. Its so slow to use since you have to keep downloading the damn webpages of the software interface.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft access can do it for mySQL

[Here is more information on the topic](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204346-subdatasheets-how-use-subform)

It indicates that you can open a Table or a Query then in the insert menu select subdatasheet. Then you use the child and link Master fields to get the display you are looking for.

You could also try the database client in openoffice.org

Unfortunately I was checking out Navicat but it does not do what you are looking for so all I found was Microsoft Access.